# Why does Django keeps asking content types are stale and need to be deleted

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-modeladmin, django-model-utils

I've tried everything found:

[Can stale content types be automatically deleted in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869414/can-stale-content-types-be-automatically-deleted-in-django)

[Deleting unused Models, stale content types prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540060/deleting-unused-models-stale-content-types-prompt)

[InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'users.GroupProxy'>]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267237/invalidbaseserror-cannot-resolve-bases-for-modelstate-users-groupproxy)

[Django Wagtail CMS migrate: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'app.CustomPage'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521984/django-wagtail-cms-migrate-cannot-resolve-bases-for-modelstate-app-custompa)

[Django migrate with zinnia- InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'zinnia.Author'>]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796128/django-migrate-with-zinnia-invalidbaseserror-cannot-resolve-bases-for-models)

So here's my problem: I have:

- a `ComicBook` that has a many-to-many `Planche`'s
- a `Planche` that has a many-to-many `Bande`'s
- a `Bande` that has a many-to-many `Vignette`'s
- ... and three levels deeper (it's not important it's always the same principle)

I needed in-between many-to-many tables to add "`importance`" field to be able to make a custom sort of the relationships. Thus I've created

- a `ComicBookPlanche` that is the many-to-many table with field `importance`
- a `PlancheBande` that is the many-to-many table with field `importance`

Everything was working perfectly until I decide to rename `ComicBook` to `Book`. From now on I always get the message `django.db.migrations.state.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for...`

I even tried to *drop all the tables* **and** *migration folder*, nothing changed... I tried to comment my application -> great then un-comment and still:

```
django.db.migrations.state.InvalidBasesError:
Cannot resolve bases for
[<ModelState: 'main.TexteLongTextesThrough'>,
 <ModelState: 'main.TexteCourtTextesThrough'>,
 <ModelState: 'main.VignetteBullesThrough'>,
 <ModelState: 'main.LivrePlanchesThrough'>]
```

I'm getting mad. So here's what I did:

- brand new application
- `makemigrations` then `migrate` -> auth, admin, sessions, sites created no problem
- copy/paste my `models.py` *without* `admin.py`.

`makemigrations` -> perfect:

```
Migrations for 'main':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Bande
    - Create model BandeVignette
    - Create model Bulle
    - Create model ContenuCourt
    - Create model ContenuLong
    - Create model Langue
    - Create model Livre
    - Create model Personne
    - Create model Planche
    - Create model PlancheBande
    - Create model TexteCourt
    - Create model TexteLong
    - Create model Vignette
    - Add field description to planche
    - Add field planches to livre
```

Then `migrate` -> perfect:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, sites, auth, contenttypes, main
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying main.0001_initial... OK

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Then copy/paste my `admin.py` then  `makemigrations` -> perfect:

```
Migrations for 'main':
  0002_livreplanchesthrough_textecourttextesthrough_textelongtextesthrough_vignettebullesthrough.py:
    - Create proxy model LivrePlanchesThrough
    - Create proxy model TexteCourtTextesThrough
    - Create proxy model TexteLongTextesThrough
    - Create proxy model VignetteBullesThrough

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Then each time I try `migrate` it keeps asking me this, no matter if I anwser "yes" or "no":

```
>>> migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, sites, auth, contenttypes, main
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

    main | textelong_textes
    main | textecourt_textes
    main | livre_planches
    main | vignette_bulles

Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.

    Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel:  yes
Process finished with exit code 0
```

What can I do to make him stop asking, and what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things here: It looks like you created the models in one batch of migrations, and then created the through tables in a second batch of migrations. This is wrong, you should have the through tables written and migrated at the same time of the main models.

What happened in the last example is that when you first created the models, django went and created it's own standard through tables, then you went and added custom through tables, so django is asking you to delete the original (old) ones.

The way you've worded everything, it looks like you placed the model definitions for the through tables in `admin.py`? Why would you do that? They should be in `models.py` right next to the models they are "connecting".

Also, you shouldn't be using a `Proxy` model, and without the actual source code, that may very well be the root cause of your problem. If all you're trying to do is have an extra field on the through relationship, you should follow the pattern here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: I think you're right. I found out that the problem is (1) I can declare my models like `Bande`, `Vignette` and `BandeVignette` **without** explicitly declaring that `BandeVignette` is a proxy (`through='BandeVignette'`) and then when I copied/pasted the `admin.py`, django kinddof "discovered" I had proxy table and tried to create them. So this is either strange, or a problem: you should **not** be able to declare a `Vignette.bulles.through` in the `admin.py` if it's not properly declared in `models.py`, but it seems that you can do that. And this caused the problem.

Comment: So I check your answer as valid because you give enough advices to put newcomers on the right track. Thank you very much